# Apps that use offline functionality now need to pester users?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, offlineapps

I have an app that is not interactive - users authenticate the app once, and the app runs in the background using the procured access token.  With the upcoming offline_access deprecation, will the app now have to send reminders (every 60 days!) to users to log back in?

This seems annoying at best, and it gives these types of apps a poor user experience (leading to loss of users, most likely).

Comment: That’s how it is from now on – deal with it :-P (Apps getting offline_access, been forgotten about by the user and then start spamming in their name several months later were the much worse user experience.)

Comment: That's too bad.  One would hope the burden would be on Facebook to detect and appropriately handle these situations.  It's unfortunate that they have chosen to pass this along as a tax on developers and their users.